# Display JSON Data from URL

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to JSON and have not been able to get the result I want. In learning, all I want to do is almost a HELLO WORLD for JSON, with the ultimate goal being to display the data in a table.

I have a JSON Call URL that gives me JSON data, and it's formatted correctly.

I have written a script to see if I can get an alert for my JSON data:

*Updated*

```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>    
   <script>
   $.getJSON("http://li93-171.members.linode.com:8080/BrokerManager/getActiveBrokerNames/?callback=?", function(data){
   console.log(data);
   });
</script>
```

Alert shown says "[object Object],[object Object]" -- I'm obviously doing something wrong. Please help!

Comment: You probably not doing it wrong, using `alert` is not the best way. use `console.log(data)` instead and see if the result is ok.

Comment: is `http://www.url.com` returning valid JSON? Try this one: `https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos` for learning purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, JSON stands for [JavaScript Object Notation](http://www.json.org/), which means when your JSON gets received by the client, jQuery will automatically change it from a normal string to a more usable Object. That is why all you see in the alert is `[object Object]` since alert can only display strings. All non-string values will be casted into strings.

```
alert(data);
alert(data.toString());  //both are the same
```

To display an Object for debugging usages, use `console.log` or

```
$("<pre>").html(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)).appendTo("body");
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/4XayF/

Comment: I have updated my code to use console.log, but am still getting the 'object Object' -- I will update the main question with live data.

Comment: @user3272262 - You shouldn't be getting that.

Comment: @user3272262 - Everything's working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/8V3tz/ I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: I'm trying to return the dataset from the JSON URL. Nothing is displaying.

Comment: @user3272262 - Have you clicked on the arrow on the left of `[object Object]`?

Comment: I get this error in Chrome. "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access." -- maybe this is a local issue for me.

Comment: @user3272262 - Are you testing it on a local server? But anyway it shouldn't matter because same origin policy does not apply to JSONP.

Comment: I was testing using my local machine to the url in the question. I uploaded the html file to my server, and get the same error. Thank you for your help, I'm going to try again tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

don't use `alert` use `console.log(data)` with objects

if you are using chrome click <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> to view your console , IE hit <kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: In Chrome, it's Ctrl + Shift + J for the JavaScript console and both Ctrl + Shift + I and F12 works.